# Dynamically created hyperlinks to call a c# function

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink

I have a function that connects to mssql database and and returns a list of stories - those stories are put in Hyperlinks. Here is my code for that:

```
public void getSocialStories()
{
    string user = getSelectedUser();
    List<SocialStory> stories = new List<SocialStory>();
    stories = functions.getSocialStories(user);

    foreach (SocialStory story in stories)
    {
        HyperLink storyLink = new HyperLink();
        storyLink.NavigateUrl = "http://google.com";

        storyLink.Text = story.Social_story_name;
        ph.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
        ph.Controls.Add(storyLink);
    }
}
```

So far so good, but now I want when a hyperlink is clicked to call a function that asks the database to return the corresponding pictures for that story. All that I need to do is something like  calling `function(story_id)`. My `List<SocialStory>` contains SocialStory objects, which have the `story_id` parameter. How can I call a function with the `story_id` as a parameter?

Comment: Set up the hyperlink accordingly to call the function on click.

Comment: i am not sure i understand what you mean. Can you explain more ?

Comment: Ah, you need it to call a _C#_ function from your page? There's no C# code at the client's side, is it?

Comment: When is this function `getSocialStories` called ? on Page_Load event ?

Comment: No, there is no client side code. I have a jQuery dialog that pops up and the hyperlinks are generated. When I click on some of them I want to be able to load different pictures. But for that purpose I need the id of the clicked story. @Amin Sayed Yes, it is called on Page_Load.

Answer (score 2):

You can use dynamic handler (ashx) to display images inside a tag.
So you will need to compose literal control something like this:

```
<a href="yourStoryLink"><img src="StoryImageHandler.ashx?storyId=yourStoryId" /></a>
```

Check [ASP.NET ASHX Handler](http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx) to get basic instructions for creating your StoryImageHandler.ashx.

Answer (score 1):

There's no C# at the client's side so you need to make an AJAX call or otherwise query the server somehow.

[How to call server side function from client side by passing the argument also? : The Official Microsoft ASP.NET Forums](http://forums.asp.net/t/1790155.aspx/1) lists a few possible solutions:

- [ScriptManager's EnablePageMethods](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/),
- [implementing ICallBackEventHandler](http://www.intstrings.com/ramivemula/asp-net/jumpstart-8-making-client-callbacks-by-implementing-icallbackeventhandler-interface/),
- a [separate WebMethod script](http://dotnetplace.com/post/Fill-ASPNETDropdownlist-through-JSON-data-using-jQuery.aspx).

They all are based on the same principle: the client sends a second request which invokes a somewhat independent piece of code. They are also considered a lighter alternative to ASMX.

- [An ASHX handler suggested by Gregor Primar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13911892/dynamically-created-hyperlinks-to-call-a-c-sharp-function#answer-13912085) is of no principal difference from the WebMethod option.

Comment: Okay, but how can I call the AJAX? In the above examples it happens with a `asp:Button with onClick`. But in my case in my aspx page all I have is `<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="ph"></asp:PlaceHolder>`, which gets filled with hyperlinks from the c# function. So I guess I need something like onClick on the hyperlinks which invokes the AJAX.

Comment: Yes, an `onclick` handler or `NavigateUrl` in the form `javascript:<statement>`. The ajax call is made with `$.ajax(<arguments>)` as it is said in the first example on the linked thread.